# Trouble Calling a Class in Another Python File

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, instantiation

I'm trying to teach myself Python, and I've ran into a problem. I'm currently running pydev if that affects anything.

Here is my class in a file called "Stock":

```
class Stock(object):
'''
A stock traded on the NASDAQ
'''


def __init__(self, ticker, company, isETF, NASDAQSymbol, price):
    '''
    Returns a stock object with a set ticker, company, ETF flag, NASDAQ Symbol and price
    '''
    self.ticker = ticker
    self.company = company
    self.isETF = isETF
    self.NASDAQSymbol = NASDAQSymbol
    self.price = price
```

I want to create an instance of this class in another file I've called "Main":

```
import urllib.request
from Stock.py import Stock

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with urllib.request.urlopen('ftp://ftp.nasdaqtrader.com/SymbolDirectory/nasdaqtraded.txt') as response:
        html = response.read()
    rawStockList = html.splitlines()

for i in rawStockList:
    stockInfo = i.split('|')
    stock = Stock(stockInfo[1], stockInfo[2], stockInfo[5], stockInfo[10], 0)
```

I get the error at the import "Unresolved import: Stock". When I comment out this line, I get an error at the "stock = Stock(...)" line that says "Undefined variable: Stock". For the record, both files are in the same folder / project within Pydev.

I have done a lot of googling and have not encountered a problem similar enough to mine that had a helpful solution. Any guidance, pointers or help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`from Stock import Stock` - you don't put the file name in a from statement; it takes the module name instead.

You should also indent your `if` statement so its in the same indentation level as your `with` statement (unless that's an error in copy-pasting your code):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with urllib.request.urlopen('ftp://ftp.nasdaqtrader.com/SymbolDirectory/nasdaqtraded.txt') as response:
        html = response.read()
    rawStockList = html.splitlines()

    for i in rawStockList:
        stockInfo = i.split('|')
        stock = Stock(stockInfo[1], stockInfo[2], stockInfo[5], stockInfo[10], 0)
```

Finally, keep in mind that although you are looping over `rawStockList`, you keep overwriting the `stock` variable in your loop. In effect, your `stock` instance will only reflect the data of the last item in `rawStockList`.

If you want to create `Stock` items for all the data in `rawStockList`, you'll need to save each item separately:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with urllib.request.urlopen('ftp://ftp.nasdaqtrader.com/SymbolDirectory/nasdaqtraded.txt') as response:
        html = response.read()
    rawStockList = html.splitlines()

    stocks = []  # This is an empty list
    for i in rawStockList:
        stockInfo = i.split('|')
        stock = Stock(stockInfo[1], stockInfo[2], stockInfo[5], stockInfo[10], 0)
        stocks.append(stock)
    print(stocks)
```